# Windows Phone 8.1 runtime: How to launch the photo gallery app from my own app?

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-runtime, windows-phone-8.1, launcher

I know it could be done this way

```
 Windows.System.Launcher.LaunchUriAsync(new System.Uri(""));
```

but I don't know the uri of the default app to show the photo gallery.
Or is there another way?

Comment: I think you have to pass in the filename of the photo, not the name of the app.  Windows will use the default app to open the photo.

Comment: ok, so how to call the default app without a filename?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunatelly if you want just open pictures app, this is impossible. 
Not all applications support launching by uri and we have very poor documentation.

List of supported apps is avaiable for example here (this is the biggest):
http://blog.mrlacey.co.uk/2014/03/1192-windows-phone-apps-that-have.html

You can just pick photo using `FileOpenpicker` (http://windowsapptutorials.com/windows-phone/media/using-fileopenpicker-in-windows-phone-8-1-to-choose-picture-from-picture-gallery/).

Comment: thank you very much, FileOpenPicker is very useful, it can create a page with a gallery of thumbnails

Comment: hi, just a little doubt, how could I remove the bottom toolbar from the Picker page? there is an icon to open a camera and I don't need it